# Build specific grouping in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to perform some manipulations with my initial dataframe - more here http://screencast.com/t/Qp5h9mOKIZf1

```
   MATCH              EVENT                      SELECTION  ODDS         
1   A-B             Correct Score                    1 - 0  11.00        
2   A-B             First Half Goals 0.5   Under 0.5 Goals   5.00 
3   B-D             Over/Under 1.5 Goals    Over 1.5 Goals   1.50
```

and get target dataframe as shown here

```
   MATCH    "Correct Score_1-0" "First..._...0.5 Goals" "Over/Under..._...1.5 Goals"         
1   A_B                   11.00           5.00                     NULL
2   B_D                    NULL           NULL                     1.50
```

Once I try to runt the code

```
df = df.set_index(['MATCH', 'EVENT', 'SELECTION', 'ODDS']).unstack(['EVENT', 'SELECTION'])
df = df.swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)
df = df.reindex(columns=events, level=0)
df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(bet, hw) for bet, hw  in df.columns]
pd.options.display.width = 200
```

It didn't help, and raise the error:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

**EDIT:**
I was able to achieve similar grouping, but not exact as I asked -

```
df = df.set_index(['MATCH', 'EVENT', 'SELECTION', 'ODDS']).unstack(['EVENT', 'SELECTION'], append=True)
df = df.swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)
df = df.reindex(columns=events, level=0)
# df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(bet, hw) for bet, hw  in df.columns] - raise error
```

http://screencast.com/t/viRYB8IE9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you case, you need to combine two columns Event and SELECTION first. And then use pivot_table attribute to reshape you data.

```
df['event_selections'] = data.EVENT + '_' + data.SELECTION
df.pivot_table(index = "MATCH",columns="event_selections",values='ODDS')
```

Comment: Perfect! Can you advise how I can add filtering for `data.Event`? I'd like to get only some columns from `EVENT`

Comment: You can filter you data by adding filter conditions, for example, you want to the string matches certain string say **Score**, you can do it using `df_new = df[df.EVENT.str.contains("Score")]`. You can refer [here] (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern)